# Must party members be present for coop achievements?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

If all other party members are *in town, in another zone, or dead* during an event OR boss battle (one that awards a "cooperative achievement"), will the event/boss battle still award the coop achievement for the whole party?

For example, the other party member in a two-person party stays in town during [an event]—does he still get the achievement, and do both get the cooperative achievement even though the other party member wasn't present? Or everyone declines a boss battle while one person finishes it—do all party members get the achievement AND the coop achievement?

Comment: Intresting question, I have never been faced with this in game. I know they will complete quests no matter where they are if they are in the same game. I also do not think you can start a boss fight without everyone accepting and teleporting into the fight.

Comment: If one+ people decline the "Accept", you're prompted with a modal asking if you want to continue anyway, so that part is possible. The other party members can't enter that area until the current party members finish the event

Comment: For a very early 2016 update, it is possible to not get a boss-related achievement if the party continues on with a boss fight after you decline. It appears a different game needs to be used to obtain it in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, both members have to be with each other to receive the achievement when it involves killing something or exploring, etc.

**Example:** When I was playing Co-op with a friend, he killed his first rare monster which triggered an achievement and I was back in town - clearing my inventory and repairing.  I did not get this achievement (I had to earn this at a different time).

Although, if the achievement is quest related - all members of the party complete the quest at the same time which [I would think] *should* trigger that specific achievement.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the talking barrel achievement while my friend stayed in town. We both got it, so i guess it works. Don't know about the boss battle cancel. Gonna try it in my next session.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even if you are fighting right next to that person, it doesn't mean you will get every achievement he gets.  Since there is achievements for so many different aspects of the game, obviously you won't get all the same ones.  But as far as progression achievements go, as long as your in the game, and your not opting out of a event, then you should be staying up to date with your party's progression achievements. At least from my experience...

Also D3 is clearly having lots of issues, maybe it was a isolated incident?  I know I've had some pretty weird glitches.  Right after I got to act 1 inferno, and I never went anywhere but act 1, I noticed that I had "completed" quest 7 in act 3.  it wasn't until I beat act 1 that I was even able to go to act 2, and I still have that quest 7 in act 3 that I can go back to any time I feel like getting 1 shot :P